# Python Pandas Groupby Behavior

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, ipython

I am trying to understand/use the groupby in Pandas to obtain the maximum count within each group and then return the row with the max count

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['alpha','beta','gamma','delta','epsilon'], 'year':[2000,2001,2000,2001,2000], 'count':[1,25,11,20,8]})
df


    count   name    year
0   1       alpha   2000
1   25      beta    2001
2   11      gamma   2000
3   20      delta   2001
4   8       epsilon 2000

df.groupby('year').max()

        count   name
year        
2000    11      gamma
2001    25      delta
```

I am grouping by year but I'd like the output to look like:

```
        count   name
year        
2000    11      gamma
2001    25      beta
```

So, I'd like to return the entire row from each group (by 'year') based on the maximum count. It also isn't clear to me why the year 2001 returns "delta" in the name rather than "beta" (as I would expect).

Comment: The reason it gives delta is that when you do `.max()` on the groupby object directly, it computes the max separately for each column.  `"delta"` is later in the alphabet and hence "greater than" `"beta"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idxmax` to collect the index of the maximum row, and then use `df.iloc` to select the row:

```
In [73]: df.iloc[df.groupby('year')['count'].idxmax()].set_index('year')
Out[73]: 
      count   name
year              
2000     11  gamma
2001     25   beta
```

---

Note that `df.groupby('year').max()` is finding the `max` for each column -- both the `count` and the `name`. That is why `delta` was getting selected as a `max` in the `name` column.

If you are only interested in the max count, then use

```
df.groupby('year')['count'].max()
```

---

`df.groupby('year')` is a `DataFrameGroupBy` object.
`df.groupby('year')['count']` is a `SeriesGroupBy` object. The call to `max` or `idxmax` on the `SeriesGroupBy` object uses values only from the `count` column. This method of restricting the GroupBy object is [documented here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby).

Comment: @unubtu: Can you explain: (i) why my command returns delta instead of beta? and (ii) what does "df.groupby('year')['count']" do? I understand df.groupby('year') but I can't decipher the "['count']" part

Answer (score 0):

You can use the general `groupby().apply` and return the rows whose `count` is equal to the group's maximum `count`. As in the other answer, the `set_index` is used to get rid of the extra `year` column.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['alpha','beta','gamma','delta','epsilon'], 'year':[2000,2001,2000,2001,2000], 'count':[1,25,11,20,8]})

>>> df.groupby("year").apply(lambda g: g[g["count"] == g["count"].max()]).set_index("year")
      count   name
year              
2000     11  gamma
2001     25   beta
```